# Dying rose plant

Tags: houseplants

[image]I am from Mumbai India. I purchased rose plant 3 weeks ago from a local nursery in March & put the plant in a pot containing potting soil & kept the plant in partial shade in balcony. I added vermi compost to potting soil. Now after  3 weeks leaves at the bootom of the plant slowly turning yellow. I watered plant less every day. But still plant is dying. So help me how to protect plant from dying.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the rose is dying. Could you add a photo of the top of the rose? To me it seems just changing leaves (the bottom one are yellow), the middle one are good. We cannot see the new one. These will be the indicator of a dying plant.

Comment: Were you instructed to leave it in partial shade? I would agree, there is nothing to indicate to me that the plant is dying. It could be going through shock from the transplant.

Comment: I cant see new leaves sprouting, that is the indicator of dying plant. Please help?

Comment: I cannot find new leaves that means plant dying.

Comment: No new growth is not an indicator of a dying rose. New growth happens mostly in spring  / the beginning of the vegetative season, less during the later months.